# How To Prevent Reload in a PHP page

Tags: php

How can I prevent a user from actions like: accessing page from reloading, double clicking and multiple windows.

Several bank  websites blocked users from reloading and multiple window opening, like for example: icicibank.com or onlinesbi.com.

Comment: So, you want to break the internet, the back button, the operating system. Do you want to control their whole pc or just the browser? And yes, irony. The question is, why do you need that. What are your specific needs?

Comment: you mean preventing that a form can be submitted multiple times?

Comment: Banks do not prevent you from opening another window, but they might only limit the active session to one to prevent confusion (on both sides).

Answer (score 1):

Long answert short: you can't.

The browser isn't yours, it's the users. Don't tell him what to do.

What you can do, is *punishing* them when they do so. Like, showing him a javascript popup asking him not to, and prevent the page to show again if he refreshes, using a token for instance.